# How to format phone number from a child input with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to format the child input to phone. I think there's something wrong to the phone format when apply to the destination. But I can't figure.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.src').on('input', function() {
    var $src = $(this);
    var dst = $src.data('dest');
    $('.tel #' + dst).val($src.val().replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3'));
//apply the format to input .tel and # from data-dest
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Src 1: <input type="text" class="src" data-dest="dest1"> 
Dest 1: <input type="text" id="dest1" readonly><br /> 
Src 2: <input type="text" class="src" data-dest="dest2"> 
Dest 2: <input type="text" class="tel" id="dest2" readonly>
```

I expect `dest1` to duplicate data from `src1`. But `dest2` format in phone number as well.

Comment: Use `$('#' + dst)` instead of `$('.tel #' + dst)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - just use `$('#' + dst)` it is an ID, they are unique, no need to prefix with class

2 - Your first input has no class `tel`

3 - `$('.tel #' + dst)` targets an element inside of the tel class(descendent) which you don't have

4 - in the new jquery it is recommend that you use `$(function() {` instead of the good old document ready. They both work currently

```js
$(function() {
  $('.src').on('input', function() {
    var $src = $(this);
    var dst = $src.data('dest');
    $('#' + dst).val($src.val().replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3'));
//apply the format to input .tel and # from data-dest
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Src 1: <input type="text" class="src" data-dest="dest1"> 
Dest 1: <input type="text" id="dest1" readonly><br /> 
Src 2: <input type="text" class="src" data-dest="dest2"> 
Dest 2: <input type="text" class="tel" id="dest2" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```js
$('.tel#' + dst)
```

without the space before the hashtag since you want to match the element with both class "tel" and id "destX".

But writing in the first input won't have any effect as there is no such class on it.

Comment: No need to include `.tel` it's an ID, also it won't work for one since there is no `.tel` on it

Comment: Yep if the goal is to have both fields copying themselves then it can be removed. Not sure what @Wilf is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no `tel` class it doesn't find the `dest` elements:
Use `#dest1` as selector for destination.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.src').on('input', function() {
    var $src = $(this);
    const formattedphone = $src.val().replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3'); 
    $('#dest1').val(formattedphone);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Src 1: <input type="text" class="src" data-dest="dest1" maxlength="10"> 
Dest 1: <input type="text" id="dest1" readonly><br /> 
<br>

Src 2: <input type="text" class="src" data-dest="dest2" maxlength="10"> 
Dest 2: <input type="text" class="tel" id="dest2" readonly>
```